# Monitoring data usage per destination ip address

Tags: networking, server, 20.04

I have client which wants to know how much internet we are using with our virtual machine on their work site. I've looked into programs such as "vnstat" which is great for the total usage for one or more interfaces, but I need to know if the traffic is on the local network or internet. Since we are using a lot of local video streams, the numbers tend to be high, so just checking if it's a little or a lot is not possible.

Does anyone know of a program that can do this? Would be alright if it just generates a log file with accumulated usage per IP address or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ntop which is not free or you can search for free alternatives https://alternativeto.net/software/ntop/?license=free